# Grant GitHub repository access to organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

I have a private GitHub repository to which I need to give customer organizations read only access. I want to let each customer decide which personal GitHub accounts are granted access, but I want to be able to add/remove access to the customer organization as a whole.

Is there a well established solution for this? Or at least does anyone have a suggestion for an approach. I am new to the GitHub platform.